# How does `lens` work?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I mean, not the simple stuff like this (from [here](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html)):

```
strike :: StateT Game IO ()
strike = do
    lift $ putStrLn "*shink*"
    boss.health -= 10
```

But things like using lens to map over types from `Linear`. How would I express this in terms of lens:

```
vecMod :: (Integral a) => V2 a -> V2 a -> V2 a
vecMod (V2 x1 y1) (V2 x2 y2) = V2 (x1 `mod` x2) (y1 `mod` y2)
```

Another example: my current code is full of small expressions like this:

```
isAt :: Thing -> Position -> Game Bool
isAt thing pos = do
  b <- use board
  return $ elem thing (b ! pos)
```

(where board is `Array (V2 Int)`)

I guess is that there (with `lens`) there is a more canonical way to express this.

In general: how do I find out what lens is able to do, what not and how it is done?

Comment: The second one could be written as `get <&> elemOf (board . ix pos . traverse) thing`, not sure if that's simpler

Comment: @bennofs Not really :)

Comment: Hmm ... how would I get the result out of: `board . ix pos . to (elem thing)` ?

Answer (score 1):

The first vecMod is easy to simplify:

```
import Control.Applicative

data V2 a = V2 a a  deriving Show

instance Functor V2 where
    fmap f (V2 x y) = V2 (f x) (f y)

instance Applicative V2 where
    pure x = V2 x x
    (V2 f g) <*> (V2 x y) = V2 (f x) (g y)

vecMod1,vecMod2 :: (Integral a) => V2 a -> V2 a -> V2 a
vecMod1 (V2 x1 y1) (V2 x2 y2) = V2 (x1 `mod` x2) (y1 `mod` y2)
vecMod2 = liftA2 mod
```

You can see liftA2 works because I made V2 applicative in the obvious way.

The second is already quite terse.  If you post a collections of such snippets we could help abstract a few things.

Comment: Hmm ok ... this is easier right. But still the question on how to find useful information in the `lens` library stands.

Comment: The Functor/Applicative instances for V2 are already defined in the linear package

Comment: @bennofs yep ... i noticed that. Actually I was thinking about tuples where no such method exists.