# How to snoc using the lens library?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I am stumped [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947136/how-does-lens-work) while trying to work with Edwards `lens` library. I try to `snoc` something onto the end of a vector in a state context:

```
data Foo = Foo {
  _vec :: Vector Int
}

makeLenses ''Foo

testCons x = vec <>= singleton x
```

While this works I'd like to use `[cons][2]` but I have no idea how. The documentation mentions `[0,1,2] |> 3 === [0,1,2,3]` but I have no idea how to do this in the state context.

Comment: Are you going to be appending elements a lot? If so, you should use a [Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Sequence.html) instead. consing/snocing a Vector is O(n), but O(1) for a Sequence; on the other hand, Sequences have O(log n) random access compared to O(1) for a Vector.

Comment: @Kata yay ... I know :-) ... I should probably use `Foo f a = Foo (f a)` in the real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (%=) combinator lets you apply a function to the target of a Lens; you want something like

```
stateSnoc :: MonadState Foo m => Int -> m ()
stateSnoc x = vec %= (|> x)
```

Comment: While this would work I am missing some of the elegance of other `lens` functions.

Comment: What do you mean 'elegance'?

Comment: I was expecting something like `vec += x`. Although that is of course reserved for `Num`.

Comment: This is about as pretty as you're going to get it, I think. There's no setter that points 'behind' the last element since, well, what would be the point? There'd never be any interesting values there.

Comment: Accepted because it's obviously correct. But I suggest to read the other answer too.

Answer (score 1):

`snoc` seems to be a plain function defined for convenience's sake from the original `Prism`, which is `_Snoc`.

So why not use a plain `MonadState` function with it, like [`modify`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#v%3amodify)?

```
runState (modify $ flip snoc 'a') ['b']
-- ((),"ba")
```

Comment: I would have to combine this with `zoom` to focus on a nested entry ... But is there a way to use `_Snoc` directly? Like `foo . vec . _Snoc  .= bar`?

Comment: The default direction of the `_Snoc` prism is from a collection to a pair of `(collection minus the last element, last element)`. But you can "turn it around" with the `review` function, and write something like `review _Snoc $ (['b'],'a')`. This is almost the definition of `snoc`, but uncurried. Be aware however that `review _Snoc` is not a lens, but a regular function.

Comment: Correction: the result of `review` works in any `MonadReader`.

Comment: Hmm ... it's not getting better :) ... My guess was that there is some kind of lens/setter that points 'behind' the container.

Comment: @Florian I doubt that there is a `Setter` that can be used to append to containers. One of the (pretty intuitive) laws that `Setters` must respect is that setting two times with two different values is equal to setting only one time with the last value. But appending 'a' and then 'b' to something is not equal to appending only 'b'! I suspect that appending and deconstruction are inherently `Prism`-like.